# How add proxy to Spynner

Tags: python, proxy, spynner

This code not change browser ip. 2ip.ru show my real ip.

```
import spynner

def main():
    b = spynner.Browser(user_agent='Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.10')
    b.set_proxy("91.208.__.__:8080")

    b.load('http://2ip.ru')
    b.browse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe just stating the obvious here, but are you sure that the proxy you are using is fully anonymous a.k.a elite?